# Flex creates margin that won't go away

Tags: css, margin, flexbox

I am using `display:flex` in order to center/vertically center the content on the page. I have set a media query so that there is a hamburger menu for mobile size. However, there appears to be a right margin on the `homePage`. No matter what I try, I can't get the margin to go away. Here's a jsfiddle of it. Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/crcommons/Lxepj9ko/2/
(p.s. make sure you adjust the browser size so that it is in mobile).

```js
$('.hamburger').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle();
});

function setPageHeight () {
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();
 var headerHeight = $('header').height();
 pageHeight = (windowHeight - headerHeight);
 $('.homePage').css('min-height', pageHeight + 'px');
};

setPageHeight();

$(window).resize(setPageHeight);
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: .75em;
}
.mainNav {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainNav li {
    width: 19%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainNav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    line-height: .3em;
}
.hamburger:before {
    content: "≡";
}
.homePage {
    background-color: #CBD5D2;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.introduction {
    max-width: 40em;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
}
.tagline {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
.introduction p {
    text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .wrapper {
        padding: 1.5em;
    }
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .hamburger {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: right;
    }
    .navigation {
        float: left;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        background: gray;
    }
    .mainNav {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .mainNav li {
        display: block;
        padding: .5em;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .homePage {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    .tagline {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="hamburger"></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="navigation menu">
                <ul class="mainNav">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Page 1</li>
                    <li>Page 2</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="homePage">
      
            <div class="introduction">
                <h1 class="logo">Title</h1>
                <h2 class="tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                <p class="introP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis nam velit, voluptates dolore consequuntur ea tempore laborum mollitia, corporis impedit distinctio aperiam itaque perspiciatis repellat neque facilis esse molestiae maiores eum, incidunt eius quaerat! Dicta illo ut, incidunt ratione magni cum unde architecto obcaecati illum harum tempora veniam placeat voluptatem.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve this would be within the `.hamburger` class media query setting `position: absolute; right: 0px;`

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly. Do you know why flex caused that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `.hamburger` is floating right, and there is nothing to clear the float. `.homepage` has a `max-width: 100%` but the width is not set. Since the homepage isn't 100%, it will float around the hamburger.

Clear the float:

```
header::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Set homepage width to 100%:

```
.homepage {
    background-color: #CBD5D2;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```